# calculate average waiting time for a preemptive shortest job first scheduling algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, operating-system

My target is to calculate average waiting time for a preemptive shortest job first scheduling algorithm.

Assume the arrival times for the jobs are in intervals of 2 units, like 0,2,4,6..... Ie, 1st job enters in 0 units and 2nd job after 2 units of time and so on.

I tested for 3 test cases for my program and got right answers:

> Test case 1:
>   jobs:8,4,9,5
>   avg Time:6.5
>
> Test case 2:
>   jobs:7,4,1,4
>   avg Time:3

But when I took a file having 1000 jobs as input I got avg Time:16872.434
But the code i got from internet gave me answer as avg Time : 16024
I didn`t understand how to attach that text file here...
so, I just want to know if my code is right? if not where did I go wrong.?

```
package algoritm_W4_M6;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;
/**
 * To calculate the average Waiting Time of jobs when done in shortest Job First(SJF)-Preemptive
 * @author Rahul Konda
 *
 */
public class Preemptivr_SJV {
    Vector<Float> burstTimes ;
    public Preemptivr_SJV() {
        burstTimes = new Vector<Float>();
    }
    public void loadFile() {
        try {
            float f;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("cpu_burst_times.txt"));
            while(scan.hasNext()) {
                f = Float.parseFloat( scan.nextLine());             
                burstTimes.add(f);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void readc() {
        burstTimes.add((float) 7);
        burstTimes.add((float) 4);
        burstTimes.add((float) 1);
    //  burstTimes.add((float) 8);
        burstTimes.add((float) 4);
    //  burstTimes.add((float) 2);
    }
    public float calculateAvgWaitingTime() {
//      readc(); //this is for test cases 1 and 2
        loadFile(); //this is to read from file
        float waitingTime= 0.0f;
        float totalTime = 0.0f;

        PriorityQueue<Float> pq = new PriorityQueue<Float>();

        for (Float time : burstTimes) {
            pq.add(time);
            Float minTime = pq.poll();
            if(time<=2) {
                waitingTime = waitingTime +(minTime*pq.size());
                continue;
            }
            waitingTime = waitingTime +2*pq.size();
            pq.add(minTime-2);//as job not completed I add back to queue
        }
        totalTime = totalTime + waitingTime;    //summing up the above waiting times
        waitingTime = 0.0f;
        while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
            waitingTime = waitingTime +pq.poll();
            totalTime = totalTime + waitingTime;    //summing up the above waiting times
        }

        totalTime = totalTime - waitingTime;
        System.out.println("Jobs burst values:\n"+burstTimes.toString());
        return (totalTime/1000);



    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Preemptivr_SJV fs = new Preemptivr_SJV();
        System.out.println("\nAverage Waiting Time is: "+fs.calculateAvgWaitingTime());
    }
}
```

The above code is in java and thanks in advance.!

Comment: The information that it's Java should be in the tags to your question (I've added it). There's no need to SHOUT YOUR QUESTION; doing so won't get you an answer any faster, makes the question more difficult to read, is rather annoying, and wastes the time of people who have to edit to fix it. It's also considered somewhat rude. :)

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite for your comment. I only meant to give more details so that the one who tries to give solution understand what i am trying. Yet, I didn`t understand what made you to consider my question as rude and annoying. I would be thankful to you if you tell me about that, so that I do not repeat that for next time. I am just, new user to stackoverflow.

Comment: SHOUTING (typing in ALL CAPS) is considered rude, and it's annoying both to people reading it and those who have to take the time to edit to remove it. Typing in proper case, where you put thing in upper case when approprieate (such as SQL) and proper case otherwise, isn't as rude and inconsiderate, and doesn't require others to edit to fix it so it's not as annoying. :)

Answer (score 1):

The average time for test case 1 is correct if the jobs arrive respectively at times 0,1,2,3.

You need a way to specify those arriving times or to step time as you add new processes.

Here is a working implementation a Preemptive Shortest Job First Scheduling:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;


public class PreemptiveSJF {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    private int waiting = 0;
    private int numberOfProcesses = 0;

    public void addProcess(int time) {
        numberOfProcesses ++;
        pq.add(time);
    }

    public float getAverageWaitingTime() {
        while (pq.size() > 1) {
            stepTime(1);
        }

        return (float)waiting / numberOfProcesses;
    }

    public void stepTime(int timeStep) {
        int time = pq.poll();
        if (time <= timeStep) {
            waiting = waiting + time * pq.size();
        } else {
            waiting = waiting + timeStep * pq.size();
            time = time - timeStep;
            pq.add(time);
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the test cases:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;


public class PreemptiveSJFTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        PreemptiveSJF psjf = new PreemptiveSJF();
        psjf.addProcess(6);
        psjf.addProcess(8);
        psjf.addProcess(7);
        psjf.addProcess(3);
        assertEquals(7, psjf.getAverageWaitingTime(), 0.000001);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        PreemptiveSJF psjf = new PreemptiveSJF();
        psjf.addProcess(8);
        psjf.stepTime(1);
        psjf.addProcess(4);
        psjf.stepTime(1);
        psjf.addProcess(9);
        psjf.stepTime(1);
        psjf.addProcess(5);
        assertEquals(6.5f, psjf.getAverageWaitingTime(), 0.000001);
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        PreemptiveSJF psjf = new PreemptiveSJF();
        psjf.addProcess(7);
        psjf.stepTime(2);
        psjf.addProcess(4);
        psjf.stepTime(2);
        psjf.addProcess(1);
        psjf.stepTime(1);
        psjf.addProcess(4);
        assertEquals(3f, psjf.getAverageWaitingTime(), 0.000001);
    }


}
```

Always separete test cases from your code.

I hope this helps.

I believe you got examples from here:

[Shortest-Job-First Scheduling](http://siber.cankaya.edu.tr/OperatingSystems/ceng328/node123.html)